# Strokes during compression test?

Tags: engine, compression, testing

Just wondering what the general consensus out there for the amount of times the vehicle turns over during a compression test? I have heard anywhere from 5-8, and personally crank 7. What is the desired number of revolutions to ensure an accurate reading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do it until the gauge doesn't go up anymore. I am not aware of a specific number of times that it needs to be done. That usually takes 6 or 7 times, but I have never actually counted.

Comment: That's pretty much what I've been taught to do, too.

Comment: That was what I was taught also. Other cylinder plugs removed, throttle held open, choke open, crank until the gauge stops moving up.